# JIRA: How to create a filter displaying all items fixed in version x.y.z or higher across several projects?

Tags: jira

In JIRA we have set up several projects for the same software tool - one for each customer since we have to adapt the software very often to the specific requirements of the customers. So bugs, issues and feature requests in JIRA end up in different JIRA projects. When a major update of our software tool is released to all customers, we are facing the problem to create release notes containing all JIRA issues cross the various JIRA projects which have been solved e.g. in version 2.3.0.0 of the software or higher.

The standard JIRA functionality makes it very easy to create release notes within one JIRA project for a specific version, but what we need is a filter across various projects for various version numbers. Since the version field in JIRA is a text field and not a number, a query for version number > 2.3.0.0 does not work.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Atlassian support is where you'll get an answer to this http://www.atlassian.com/resources/support

Comment: Or http://answers.atlassian.com